# Find all checked nodes of parent node in treeview

Tags: vb.net, treeview, nodes

I have been trying to search the web for information regarding child nodes, but I seem to find everything but what I'm looking for.

Basically, my problem is this:
I have determined if a parent node is checked in my treeview control.  What I need to do is loop through all child nodes of this parent to determine what children are checked and then load these into an array.

As I already know the parent node, I am hoping I don't have to loop through all nodes again.  I want to just loop through all child nodes of a specified parent.

Hope that makes sense.

My Treeview looks similar to this:

```
Name
  -->Name 1
  -->Name 2
  -->Name 3
  -->Etc
Code
  -->Code 1
  -->Code 2
  -->Code 3
  -->Etc
```

So my example would look like this:

```
 If trvFilter.Nodes.Item(trvFilter.Nodes.IndexOfKey("Name")).Checked = True Then
             'Loop through Child Nodes of Parent Node (Name)
             'If Child Node is checked, add the name of the Child node to an array
         End If
```

Sorry if this seems simple, but I'm new to vb.net and can't work out how to loop through the child nodes of a selected parent.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have figured out a method of getting my end results that I required with the following code:

```
If trvFilter.Nodes.Item(trvFilter.Nodes.IndexOfKey("Name")).Checked = True Then
            'Loop through Child Nodes of Parent Node (Name)
            For Each cn As TreeNode In trvFilter.Nodes.Item(trvFilter.Nodes.IndexOfKey("Name")).Nodes
                'If Child Node is checked, add the name of the Child node to an array
                If cn.Checked Then
                    StoreRecordArray.Add(cn.Text)
                End If
            Next
        End If
```

Please feel free to update my code if there is an easier (tidier) method.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

trvFilter.Nodes is a collection of TreeNode, so you can loop through them with a for-each

```
for each tvn as TreeNode in trvFilter.Nodes

 ' do stuff with tvn

next
```